# call php function on form submition

Tags: php, html, random, onclick, call

Hi im trying to generate this a code from this php function

```
         <?php function generateRandomString($length = 6) {
    return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($x='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ceil($length/strlen($x)) )),1,$length);
}

echo  generateRandomString(); ?>
```

when this   `<button>Submit</button>` is clicked. It is a submition button for a form in HTML

Many Thanks in advance :)

Comment: have you looked into using an Ajax request to the php script to get the output of `generateRandomString()`?

Comment: the string is generating fine i just want it to execute on button click that all

Answer (score 0):

For help on the basics of setting up a ***form*** in HTML:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

You'll need to target your PHP script in the form action.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Using the script exactly as you have it will simply send the plain text random string back to your browser.